# I created button navigation in wordpress when ever I change pages navigation also be change (means too whole pages changing)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I created button navigation in wordpress when ever I change pages navigation also be change (means too whole pages changing)
I need that navigation always be there if I change the home button to shop but page is reloading and after reload it's shows navigation perfectly.
I only need the how can I change the or crate an website even if and change my page change or navbar will still have its position.